# conditional validation with yup and react hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, yup

I have add questions form, and i have validating it using yup and react hook form but this error appear to me when just form rendered, here is error ( TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce') ), and here is my yup schema

```
const schema = yup.object({
  questions: yup.array().of(
    yup.object().shape({
      subject: yup.string().required('subject is required'),
      subLevel: yup.string().required("sublevel is required"),
      difficultyLevel: yup.string().required("difficulty level is required"),
      type: yup.string().required("Answer type is required"),
      name: yup.string().required("Question is required"),
      image: yup.mixed()
        .test('fileType', 'Invalid file format', (value) => {
          if (!value || typeof value === 'string') return true;
          const supportedFormats = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png'];
          return supportedFormats.includes(value[0]?.type);
        }),
      correctOption: yup.string().when("type",{
        is: "MCQ",
        then: yup.string().required("You must enter at least one options"),
        otherwise: yup.string().notRequired(),
      }),
    })
  ),
})
```

I think that error because of the way of handle correctOption field , and I don't know if i am accessing the type field value inside when funtion in the correct way or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using yup.lazy() to dynamically define the schema based on the value of type. Here's how you can modify your schema

code

```
const schema = yup.object({
  questions: yup.array().of(
    yup.lazy((value) =>
      yup.object().shape({
        subject: yup.string().required('Subject is required'),
        subLevel: yup.string().required("Sublevel is required"),
        difficultyLevel: yup.string().required("Difficulty level is required"),
        type: yup.string().required("Answer type is required"),
        name: yup.string().required("Question is required"),
        image: yup.mixed().test('fileType', 'Invalid file format', (value) => {
          if (!value || typeof value === 'string') return true;
          const supportedFormats = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png'];
          return supportedFormats.includes(value[0]?.type);
        }),
        correctOption: yup.string().when("type", {
          is: "MCQ",
          then: yup.string().required("You must enter at least one option"),
          otherwise: yup.string().default('').notRequired(),
        }),
      })
    )
  ),
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest but the same error still appear, are you have another solution? , We can think together.